# Auto Answer "y" in terminal commands

Tags: macos, terminal, rsync

I am trying to sync files in iPhone to a remote server using rsync. While the command is executing, the terminal will throw me a promt with a question :

Do you want to continue connecting? (y/n)

What I would want is to auto answer with an option 'y'. Please help how I can achieve this using terminal commands.

Answer (score 4):

One word answer: `yes`. `yes | whatever` will output an infinite stream of `y` to the stdin of `whatever`. `yes n` would send `n` (but no argument defaults to `y`).

Comment: I tried this. It does not work with iphone terminal. :(

Answer (score -1):

try this, for more option --help or -h or -help

```
/dir/command -y
```